# Use of as much as in sentences

Tags: meaning

For example while we are going by a bus , my daughther asked me how much longer we would go , would it be correct if say the sentence  below .

> We will go for as much distance as we went until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is understandable, but not idiomatic.

Rather than *as much distance* we would normally say *as far*.

Rather than *until now* we would normally say *so far*. (*Until now* is rare, and usually implies that whatever we are talking about in the past is now changing or stopping).

This is a classic case where we would use the present perfect *have gone*, because this is an activity which has continued into the present.

So the answer could be

> We will go as far as we have gone so far.

The repetition of *far* might be awkward, but is probaly not a problem, because the idiom *so far* is accented on the "so", not the "far", so the repetition is less noticeable in speech than on the page.

To emphasis that we are talking about the part of the jouney to come, not the whole journey, we might well add "again":

> We will go as far again as we have gone so far.

This is not the usual meaning of "again" (doing something another time) but its use with measures to mean "the same amount as before".